# DocuSign API - Missing folder items

Tags: docusignapi

Using postman I'm trying to retrieve folder items for a specific template folder. I'm expecting 3 items in my results but the API call returns empty.

This is used to work till last week.

`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/folders/{{folderId}}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/reference/Folders/Folders/listItems) there is an optional query parameter `from_date` which the default search is the previous 30 days. All these days I haven't notice this parameter.

Once I set `from_date` I was able to get my expected 3 items.